# How can I export a plugin from dayjs() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dayjs

I am using the plugin ***isToday()*** to extend the functionality of ***dayjs()*** but I don't know how to export isToday() so I can use it in other files.

```
import isToday from "dayjs/plugin/isToday";

export dayjs.extend(isToday);
```

Comment: `export default dayjs;`

Answer (score 1):

You can export it as follows:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import isSameOrBefore from 'dayjs/plugin/isSameOrBefore';
import isSameOrAfter from 'dayjs/plugin/isSameOrAfter';
import 'dayjs/locale/en';

dayjs.extend(isSameOrBefore);
dayjs.extend(isSameOrAfter);

export { dayjs }; // OR export default dayjs
```

If you are using TypeScript and you want a `Dayjs` similar type, you can use:

```
// ...

const dayjsInstance = dayjs();
export type Dayjs = typeof dayjsInstance;
```